# how to convert a Picture object into a Bitmap object, Android

Tags: android, imageview, type-conversion, image

how can I convert a Picture into a Bitmap,  what I tried in the code is not working.  Any Ideas on how to do this?   I wanted to get the image in the Picture object and put that image into the ImageView named imageOne.

```
    showBitmap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            Picture picture = wv.capturePicture();

           Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(picture.getWidth(), 
                   picture.getHeight(), 
                   Bitmap.Config.RGB_565); 
   Canvas c = new Canvas(bm); 
   picture.draw(c);

   imageOne.setImageBitmap(bm);

            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the package of your Picture class ?

Comment: it is android.graphics.Picture http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Picture.html

Comment: Potentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273646/android-how-to-convert-picture-from-webview-capturepicture-to-byte-and-bac

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273646/android-how-to-convert-picture-from-webview-capturepicture-to-byte-and-bac

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add this:

```
//Convert Picture to Bitmap
private static Bitmap pictureDrawable2Bitmap(Picture picture) {
    PictureDrawable pd = new PictureDrawable(picture);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pd.getIntrinsicWidth(), pd.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawPicture(pd.getPicture());
    return bitmap;
}
```

Reference: [Android - How to convert picture from webview.capturePicture() to byte[] and back to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273646/android-how-to-convert-picture-from-webview-capturepicture-to-byte-and-bac)

Then modify your code as follows:

```
showBitmap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Picture picture = wv.capturePicture();
        Bitmap bm = pictureDrawable2Bitmap(picture); 
        imageOne.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works, But could you explain why  `Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);canvas.drawPicture(pd.getPicture());` needed. when you already have bitmap created?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static Bitmap pictureDrawable2Bitmap(Picture picture) {
    final int width = picture.getwidth();
    final int height = picture.getHeight();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawPicture(picture, new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
    return bitmap;
 }
```